# How do I get MSBuild to understand read dependencies in my tlog files?

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, msbuild-task

My end goal is to make it possible to add 3D scenes in fbx format to my solution, and make them automatically converted into sdkmesh files and dds textures when I build my solution.

To do this, I created a custom build target, which invokes the program ContentExporter.exe on the fbx files in the solution, which implements the conversion from fbx to sdkmesh and dds.

By using incremental building, I want Visual Studio to automatically re-run ContentExporter.exe on my fbx files, but only when the outputs are out of date. For example, it should rebuild if I modify the fbx file, and it should rebuild when one of the outputs is missing.

I implemented my custom build task using XamlTaskFactory. This custom task invokes the following command line:

```
"$(MSBuildBinPath)\amd64\Tracker.exe" /d "$(MSBuildBinPath)\FileTracker64.dll" /i $(TLogLocation) /r "[Inputs]" /c ContentExporter.exe [AllOptions] [Inputs]
```

This command line runs ContentExporter.exe under MSBuild's file tracker. As a result, it outputs two files in my intermediate build directory:

- ContentExporter.read.1.tlog
- ContentExporter.write.1.tlog

These files contain lists of the read/write dependencies between files during compilation. For example, ContentExporter.read.1.tlog includes (with the path on my computer replaced with `path\to\my\project`):

```
^C:\path\to\my\project\ASSETS\CUBE\CUBE.FBX
C:\path\to\my\project\ASSETS\CUBE\CUBE.FBX
C:\path\to\my\project\ASSETS\CUBE\CUBE.FBM\DEFAULT.PNG
C:\path\to\my\project\BUILD\DEFAULT.DDS
```

If I understand correctly, that means that the file tracker found that running ContentExporter.exe on cube.fbx caused ContentExporter.exe to read cube.fbx, default.png, and default.dds.

Furthermore, ContentExporter.write.1.tlog includes:

```
^C:\path\to\my\project\ASSETS\CUBE\CUBE.FBX
C:\path\to\my\project\ASSETS\CUBE\CUBE.FBM\DEFAULT.PNG
C:\path\to\my\project\BUILD\CUBE.SDKMESH
C:\path\to\my\project\BUILD\DEFAULT.DDS
```

If I understand correctly, that means that the file tracker found that running ContentExporter.exe on cube.fbx caused ContentExporter.exe to write default.png, cube.sdkmesh, and default.dds.

Using these tracker logs, I expect Visual Studio's incremental building system to be able to handle my assets. For example:

- If I modify cube.fbx, it should know that cube.sdkmesh needs to be rebuilt, since the write.1.tlog file declares that cube.fbx writes cube.sdkmesh.
- If I delete default.dds, it should know that cube.fbx needs to be rebuilt, since write.1.tlog says that default.dds is written from cube.fbx.

And indeed, in my current setup, if I delete default.dds (in my build output directory), then Visual Studio automatically notices that it needs to rebuild cube.fbx the next time I build my solution. It also rebuilds cube.fbx if I update the timestamp of cube.fbx or default.png, so it looks like the tracking is working as expected.

However, I noticed that even when I modify a completely unrelated file, like modifying any C++ source file in my project, it still rebuilds cube.fbx.

I've also tried explicitly setting the Inputs and Outputs properties of my task (eg: to "cube.fbx" and "cube.sdkmesh"). That works for rebuilding the sdkmesh when I delete the cube.sdkmesh, but it doesn't rebuild default.dds when I delete default.dds. I guess I would need a way to know the Inputs and Outputs from the tlog files, but I thought that would be done automatically?

What could be the cause of this error? Is there a part of this process that I'm not understanding?

There are some extra details specific to my project here: https://github.com/nlguillemot/ContentExporterMSBuild/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

We could not trick to getting MSBuild to properly read the tlog files the tracker produces. According to the [Incremental Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> A target element can have both an Inputs attribute, which indicates
> what items the target > expects as input, and an Outputs attribute,
> which indicates what items it produces as output MSBuild attempts to
> find a 1-to-1 mapping between the values of these attributes. If a
> 1-to-1 mapping exists, MSBuild compares the time stamp of every input
> item to the time stamp of its corresponding output item. Output files
> that have no 1-to-1 mapping are compared to all input files. An item
> is considered up-to-date if its output file is the same age or older
> than its input file or files.
>
> If all output items are up-to-date, MSBuild skips the target. This
> incremental build of the target can significantly improve the build
> speed. If only some files are up-to-date, MSBuild executes the target
> but skips the up-to-date items, and thereby brings all items
> up-to-date. This is known as a partial incremental build.

You would observed the following output that when you change any file in the project.

> Test.cpp will be compiled as ${Toolpath}\ Test.cpp was modified at
> 2/16/2017 12:19:12 PM.

**The inconsistent time stamp triggers the rebuild** other than the tlog files the tracker produces. So we could not reduce the rebuild by tricking MSBuild to properly read the tlog files the tracker produces.

Comment: If I modify Test.cpp, I expect my solution to be rebuilt, but why does that rebuild my fbx files as well?

Comment: This is likely because its part of another translational unit, other projects reference the file(s),something (perhaps a pre build event) is "touching" the files, etc. To debug this issue you can create a new Blank.cpp file, then modify the test.cpp, check whether the Black.cpp is rebuilt.

Comment: I mean, my fbx file is not a C++ file at all, it's a 3D scene file from 3ds max. Sorry, I feel like I should explain my situation better in my original question.

Comment: Hi Leo, I've updated my question with a lot more details. I would be grateful if you could take another look at it.

Comment: Does ContentExporter.exe turn any relative path specified for fbx into an absolute path? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187974/msbuild-task-items-in-subdirectories-are-incremental-builds-not-possible-on-the

Comment: My output paths are already relative to the working directory of the build system (similarly to the solution to the question you linked), so that shouldn't be a problem.
My problem is not that "Outputs" is set to the wrong location. My problem is that I need Visual Studio's build system to automatically determine Inputs and Outputs from the tracker log files.

Comment: Could not find any reference to the syntax of these .tlog files after take a long time. Actually, the tracker files are generated after the Build. Personal view, it`s rather difficult for Visual Studio to build project base on the Inputs and Outputs from the tracker log file.

Comment: Besides, I found the reason for the issue (cube.fbx was rebuilt after modify a completely unrelated file) is that no condition for the custom build target. You will find those skipped Targets "CreateTfsBuildInfoResource" in the build log were skipped by the false condition. And I also test it by writing a target without condition, then modified a unrelated file, this target would be rebuild  once the Build be executed. So if want the custom build target not to be rebuild every time, you should give this target conditions.